# What's the difference between boom, boost & rise?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

What is the difference between these 3 words in use and which is more correct with ***tourist***...

Comment: Please provide example sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a dictionary. If you visit any good dictionary, such as the Merriem-Webster online dictionary, you will be able to individually look up each word. Thereafter, you can compare the meaning of each word.